# remote ssh to machine with key -- how to avoid entering passphrase

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have two machines - call them A and B - that have an ssh key pair set up.  The key has a passphrase, but it is stored, so if I log into machine B from machine A I don't have to enter anything.

However, if I ssh to machine A from a third machine, and then try to ssh from A to B, it requires my passphrase every time.  Is there a way to avoid this?

I tried something naive like copying my ssh key to the .ssh directory of the third machine, but this didn't work.

Thanks for any help.